# Private Certificate Authority in PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, x509, pki, php-openssl

I am setting up a private CA, and I want to interface with it using PHP. I have tried with PHP's [built-in openssl library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php). So I create a CSR, and to sign it I use `openssl_csr_sign`.

This does sign the CSR, but that's it. In OpenSSL's CLI it would be something like

`openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in file.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key ...`

Whereas I want something like

`openssl ca -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -in file.csr -out file.crt ...`

Basically it uses the x509 module to sign it, instead of the ca module. So it doesn't write it into the database specified in `openssl.cnf`, it doesn't use or update the serial number; it's more "I trust this guy so I'll sign his public key with my private key" than an actual CA. Is there a way to manage a private CA in PHP, with openssl or not?

Comment: why not to use specialized CA software?

Comment: @Crypt32 for now at least, I'm making a PoC so I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: You are trying to reinvent a wheel. There are known and proven commercial/free CA software you shall use. Most of them provide APIs for use. For example, Microsoft ADCS for Windows or EJBCA for other platforms.

Comment: @Crypt32 What I have now is literally 3 function calls. I fail to see how that's a worse solution than installing and understanding a whole software suite -  what's more, _for a PoC_.

Comment: Because you are trying to do things in a wrong way. OpenSSL is just a framework, it doesn't intended to replace CA software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Despite using a provided openssl.conf file, PHP's OpenSSL extension doesn't automatically manage the certificate database and/or serial numbers, and it doesn't provide any utilities to help with that.

On the other hand, the database itself has a [relatively simple format](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cadb.html), so you can implement it yourself using the primitive file-system functions. Here are some hints if you actually go with that route:

- Since each certificate record sits on a separate line, `fgets()` comes handy while parsing it.

  - `fscanf()` looks better at first glance, but it treats all whitespace the same and tabs are an essential part of the format, so ...
  - `file()` is even easier, but only for reading. Chances are that you'll need read+write at the same time, and you'll need to obtain a lock on the file to avoid race conditions.
- The DN string elements can be in arbitrary order, not all are mandatory and the delimiter isn't escaped when present inside a value, so you'll find it hard to produce it in the same way that the OpenSSL CLI tool does. You're better off doing a [openssl_x509_parse()](https://secure.php.net/openssl_x509_parse) on the just signed certificate and reading the value from there.

  - I don't remember what it was, but that function had some minor difference in the result between PHP 5 and 7 and it was kind of important for the DN string.
- PHP (properly) handles the serial number as an integer, but it is stored in hexadecimal notation, so you'll need to convert it back and forth.

  - The serial file stores the *next* serial number, so you can do `$serial = hexdec(file_get_contents($pathToSerial))`, pass that variable to `openssl_csr_sign()` and then write `sprintf("%X\n", $serial + 1)` to the file.
- Revocation timestamps sit in the 3rd column of the database, but since you don't revoke a certificate right while signing it, it won't be present - that's why there's 2 tabs between the expiration date and serial number, don't forget that while writing.
- Contrary to what one would expect, The OpenSSL CLI tool doesn't actually operate on the same database file. It reads the current one, renames it to `<filename>.old` and then creates an entirely new one as `<filename>`. What this means is that any file-system ownership, permissions that give your PHP script access to it are lost whenever you use the CLI tool.

  - Put runtime checks for access to the file; on failure - abort generation/signing and log/print a message (possibly with `chown`, `chmod` instructions) to notify you of that.
  - Same thing applies to the serial and all other files.
- While I've never seen it happen, it's not impossible that any of key generation, CSR creation and signing fails.

  - The resulting pKey, CSR, certificate are all interdependent and of type `resource` (which should be closed after use). To throw an exception and close the resources only when necessary, I like to pre-define the variables holding them and `use` them in a closure that handles all conditional resource-free routines before throwing an exception.
  - Only write to the database after all 3 have succeeded, and write to the serial file last.
- You've probably already figured that one out, but they pKey resource holds both the private and public keys.

As you can see, it is manageable if you know what you're doing, but it has a lot of gotchas and not really worth it for a simple PoC. Calling the CLI tool via `exec()` (and siblings) is a simpler choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed I'll `exec` my way out and I'll leave the implementers of the actual solution figure out what they want in production :>